# aliasing fields in mongodb projections

Tags: c#, mongodb

In mongo projections, you can either `include` or `exclude` fields in the output:

```
{
   IncludetField: 1,
   ExcludedField: 0
}
```

These projections are easy to create in c#, using the `ProjectionDefinitionBuilder<>` methods `Include` and `Exclude`.

MongoDb also allows for aliasing fields:

```
{
   alias: "$IncludedField"
}
```

but I havnen't found a good way of doing this without falling back to strings:

```
_collection.Aggregate()
   .Match(...)
   .Project("{alias: '$IncludedField'}");
```

This can soon become quite messy. Add a `$filter` in that projection, and you soon end up with quite a complicated string with no help from the compiler at all.

Have I overlooked something? Or is this just the way it is?

Comment: Sort of depends on what you want. If you mention `$filter` it would probably help you to be more specific here. With `AsQueryable()` expressions you can do something like `.Select( p => new { alias = p.IncludedField } )` ( from memory as not in front of IDE ). You might actually be talking about "dynamically" constructing a BSON Document input for the pipeline instead, as that's something we do in more dynamic languages, and there are ways to do that as well. So many ways to skin this cat that the question would be clearer if you were more exacting to the intent.

Comment: I hadn't considered LINQ. I try to stear away from it, cause in my experience, too many developers doesn't keep enough attention to what is being executed on server vs what is executed locally. Have found too many examples where someone has inserted an `toArray` or similar in the middle of an aggregation, causing half the db to be pulled and iterated in memory....

Comment: The `.Select( )` expression you have seems to be valid for the non-linq aggregation variant as well, and will actually take me pretty far. Still a little unsure about how to incorporate the `$filter` step, though...

Comment: That's why I was asking to be "specific". So it's still unclear what you mean. Like I said, the basic "aliasing" is trivial, and you certainly do not need "strings" just to even do things like `$filter`. In essence `{ <key> = <value> }` is pretty much valid inside each builder stage and at nested levels. And BSON Documents can be dynamically constructed. That seems to be the point you are missing, but it's unclear. If you just want "basic aliasing" then you already got the answer to that.

Comment: It’s not always easy to express what you want when you’re not sure what you’re doing :-)

Comment: Yeah! So still not sure which you were asking. The "question itself" really only references a "simple" key assignment. You mentioned `$filter` so I left the comment to ask for clarification. But for "simple key assignment" then the question appears to be answered with the simple assignment as shown in the comment. If you had something more specific to ask, then I'd suggest you asked "specifically". And probably as a new question considering the question here didn't really ask for any more than what you got. I know! It's hard sometimes, but "thems' the breaks!"

Comment: Yes, I asked for simple key assignments, and assumed a solution to that problem also would lead me to a solution for more complex assignments. And it did! @dnickless answer gave me the simple solution, and your mentioning of linq got me reading at the right page of the docs to solve the filter as well. So I'm all happy now, really ;-)

Comment: I do find working with BSON a little hard, though. But lets leave that for another time..

Comment: if you do want a more specific question, I've created one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47282404/mongo-projection-comparing-enums-as-strings :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
_collection.Aggregate()
   .Match(...)
   .Project(x => new { alias = x.IncludedField });
```